# Fees for messages received from OnSnapshot

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

What is the situation with fees when:

- I have one channel
- 10 users belong to the channel
- one of the people added a message to the channel so all users who are listening will receive the message

Costs:

*1. Adding a message costs X1*

**2. What will the cost be for everyone to read?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Adding a message costs X1

Adding a message will cost you exactly one document write.

> What will the cost be for everyone to read?

If all 10 users are reading that message, then the cost will of 10 document reads.

Comment: The cost of a request sent to Firestore for some data is the same as reading a message as a result of listening?

Comment: No, the result of sending data to Firestore will cost you a write operation. When you read a document for the first time, it will cost you one read operation. If 10 different users read the same document, the cost will be of 10 read operations.

Comment: But these 10 people did not send a request to read this message. They received this message automatically because they were listening to the channel. Does it matter? Is it the case that Firestore sent a message to these users?

Comment: Yes it does. All 10 users get that message automatically because they listen to that channel. Once a new message is added, a listener is invoked and the user gets the new message.